# DMCA Notice on Website and Effecting Traffic of all Site

Tags: performance, traffic

I have received the DMCA on my website and that is effecting the traffic of whole website. I am getting less impressions and clicks on google search console since last month. I have received the DMCA on Cloudflare. So What to do now can any help me this matter

Comment: consult a lawyer.  DMCA takedown is something you won't be able to fix from search engine DMCA takedowns.

Comment: Please do not revert moderator edits. As you can see in the edit description, we have a general policy against links to websites.